# jq merge two json files and create a key as the filename for each in merged file

Tags: json, jq

**Question**:

How do you merge multiple JSON files using jq. Each of the merged objects must have their own key name in the final merged file.

**file1.json** :

```
{
  "shoe": 0,
  "temp": "10"
}
```

**file2.json**:

```
{
  "num": {
    "sock": 0,
    "ratio": {
      "cat": 100,
      "dog": 0
    }
  },
  "hair": "blue"
}
```

**Desired merged output**:

```
{
  "file1": {
    "shoe": 0,
    "temp": "10"
  },
  "file2": {
    "num": {
      "sock": 0,
      "ratio": {
        "cat": 100,
        "dog": 0
      }
    },
    "hair": "blue"
  }
}
```

Attempt 1:
The issue with the below is that the objects hierarchy is merged if that makes sense:

```
jq --slurp 'add' file1.json file2.json
```

**Attempt 1 Output (not what I want)**:

```
{
  "shoe": 0,
  "temp": "10"
  "num": {
    "sock": 0,
    "ratio": {
      "cat": 100,
      "dog": 0
    }
  },
  "hair": "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jq` has a built-in variable  `input_filename` that represents the filename the filter is being applied on. So you can do something like

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $s (.; .[input_filename] += $s)'  file1.json file2.json
```

The `reduce` expression takes the entire input objects and constructs the final JSON with the key as the filename being used.

You can go one level further and want to optionally remove the extension part of the JSON `.json`, use the trimming functions available. The below code assumes the input file is ending with `.json` and won’t work with any other extensions

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $s (.; (.[input_filename|rtrimstr(".json")]) += $s)'
```