# how to merge folder-organized .json file into a single JSON file with folder/file names as keys

Tags: json, shell, command-line-interface, jq

I have a folder tree storing various .json files converted from a dataset. something like

```
/(top folder)
 |-- folder1/
 |    |- file1.json {"a":1,"b":[1,2]}
 |    |- file2.json {"a":12,"c":[]}
 |-- folder2/
      |- file1.json {"ta":1,"tb":[1,2]}
      |- file2.json {"ta":12,"tc":1}
      |- folder21/
          |- file3.json {"test":true}
```

I hope to merge this folder as

```json
{
   "folder1": {
      "file1.json": {"a":1,"b":[1,2]},
      "file2.json": {"a":12,"c":[]}
   },
   "folder2": {
      "file1.json": {"ta":1,"tb":[1,2]},
      "file2.json": {"ta":12,"tc":1},
      "folder21" : {
        "file3.json": {"test":true}
      }
   }
}
```

I know this is possible to do with python/perl by writing explicit loops by 1) parsing the json file, 2) merge parsed data with the native data struct/objects using file/folder names as keys, and 3) save the merged data structures into a single JSON file. I've [implemented one for Octave/MATLAB](https://github.com/NeuroJSON/jbids), and it works, but it is kind of slow.

I am wondering if it is possible to do this efficiently using jq.

I saw merging json files within the same folder is possible using the `reduce` expression, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59769797/4271392

I am wondering if jq allows to scan and iterate over sub-folders and merge through each folder.

If this is possible, I'd be appreciated if someone can point me to the related examples or documentation.

Comment: Should the order of the directories be preserved in the JSON output?

Comment: Also do you expect to have multiple more levels of depth or the one shown in the question is the maximum permissible level?

Comment: @Inian, keeping the order is preferred, but not a must if it adds significant overhead. Also, for your second question - the maximum level is not determined, but the particular data folder I work with usually have less than 5 levels.

Comment: if I am willing to combine bash with jq, would there be a way to walk through folder levels and merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention `bash` in the comments area, you can try this script calling jq :

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $s ({}; setpath(input_filename|split("/");$s) )' */**/*.json
```

My test output :

```
{
  "folder1": {
    "file1.json": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  "folder2": {
    "folder21": {
      "file3.json": {
        "test": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `setpath()`

Comment: the script above works like magic! thank you so much! (please disregard my earlier post - the script does include folder names in the output)

Comment: just a quick follow-up  question: during my per-file conversion, if I have some JSON files use different suffix, such as `a.gz.jbids` or `b.tsv.json` and I want to use the original file name `a.gz` instead of using `a.gz.jbids` as the key, where should I add `rtrimstr()` in your sample script to do this?

Comment: `split("/")` generates an array like `["folder2","folder21","a.gz.jbids"]`, you can work on that.

Comment: thanks @Philippe, `input_filename|sub(".tsv.json";".tsv")|sub(".jbids";"")|split("/")` did the trick.

Comment: Indeed, doing it before the split is easier, just less reliable, in case your folder names contain strings like `".jbids"`.